# Append main url with javascript withour refreshing the page doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list of videos on a page and i show play each video on the same page when one clicks on the video icon, My sample page url is like

`www.xyz.com/video/`

Now i have to append the url in such a way that when a user click on the video icon it should also play that perticular video on the same page and also change the url to

`www.xyz.com/video/XhskwaJS` without refresh the page. Logic behind this is to share give user ability to share each video rather than the main video page which has several videos listed

I used following code on event click to extract the VideoID and try to append it to the main URL

```
var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
var URL = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/Se1y2R5QRKU?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1'              
var match = URL.match(regExp);
                if (match && match[7].length == 11) {
                    //console.log(match[7]);
                    location.href = $(this).attr('href') + match[7];
                    return match[7];
                } else {
                    //alert("Could not extract video ID.");
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex won't match when applied to a `youtube.com` address as it requires `youtu.be`.

Maybe you can simplify the regex anyway by specifying one alternative for embed and watch urls along the lines of

```
^[^?]+/embed/([^?]+)\?
^[^?]+/watch\?v=([^&]+)
```

Finally, instead of setting `location.href` which triggers a refresh, use the html5 history api and write

```
window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', $(this).attr('href') + match[7]);
```

Comment: I had found the solution, anyways thanks as this is the correct answer.